# Adapting a JavaScript code to be dynamic

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I am kind of new in Jquery,and still learning. I am using Chart.Js in order to render data and AJAX calls.

I created a script that update a Radar Chart using a dropdown Button. The goal in mind is: 
Each user is part of a team and has some data that I render in a chart. So I there is some fixed data on the chart using a fixed_array and then the user can compare the current member with other member in the team using the drop down button

I managed to do it with static data with that code but I do not know how to make it dynamic. 
I imported the whole team data in the form {user_id : [data_array]} for example :

```
{6: [81, 68, 71, 71, 67, -72], 7: [79, 77, 86, 86, 59, -71], 8: [67, 71, 68, 68, 85, -66]}
```

and the current_user id with current_user = data.current_user that return the integer of the ID in this situation 6.

I made a try in a separate file in order to test the chart which look like the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Different arrays for the different data
        var array = [];
        array["raphael"] = [90, 20, 80, 50, 34];
        array["fraxool"] = [89, 12, 68, 89, 90];
        array["johnny"] = [78, 89, 1, 90, 80];

        // Default value
        var fixed_array = [20, 12, 78, 50, 90];

        // Chart config
        var color = Chart.helpers.color;
        var config = {
            type: 'radar',
            data: {
                labels: [["label1"], "label2", "label3", "label4", "label5"],
                datasets: [{
                    label: "Bugsy Bug 1",
                    backgroundColor: color(window.chartColors.red).alpha(0.2).rgbString(),
                    borderColor: window.chartColors.red,
                    pointBackgroundColor: window.chartColors.red,
                    data: []
                }, {
                    label: "Bugsy Bug 2",
                    backgroundColor: color(window.chartColors.blue).alpha(0.2).rgbString(),
                    borderColor: window.chartColors.blue,
                    pointBackgroundColor: window.chartColors.blue,
                    data: fixed_array
                }]
            },
            options: {
                legend: {
                    position: 'top',
                    display: false
                },
                title: {
                    display: false,
                    text: 'Fiverr Chart'
                },
                scale: {
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true
                    },
                    pointLabels: {
                        fontSize: 10,
                        lineHeight: 2
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        var mainChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas"), config);
        // Event for the select
        $(".pick-chart").change(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var val = $(this).val();
            if (val != 0) {
                config.data.datasets[0].data = array[val];
            } else {
                config.data.datasets[0].data = [];
            }
            mainChart.update();
        });
    });
</script>
```

But my actual application is getting its data using AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
  method: "GET",
  url: endpoint,
  success: function(data){
    console.log(data)
    //Labels comming from wevsite.views//

    info_array = data.info_array
    current_user = data.current_user

</script>
```

right now the output of info_array is `{6: [81, 68, 71, 71, 67, -72], 7: [79, 77, 86, 86, 59, -71], 8: [67, 71, 68, 68, 85, -66]}`

so {user_id: [data]}

and current_user output : 6
I would like to adapt it to use dynamic data that would adapt to any size of team

Could someone help me to figure it out ?

edited code V2:

```
<div class="col graph-info">

            <div class="card">
              <h5 class="card-header text-center bg-dark text-white">Information processing</h5>
              <div class="card-body">
                <div class="dropdown-container">
                        <form>
                            <select id="pick-chart" class="form-control pick-chart">
                                <option value="0">Compare with</option>
                      {% for i in team_list_pop %}
                      <option value="{{i.id}}">{{i.first_name}} {{i.last_name}}</option>
                     {% endfor %}
                            </select>
                        </form>
                    </div>

                <canvas id="info_process"></canvas>
              </div>
          </div>
<script>
var endpoint = 'api/chart/data'


$.ajax({
  method: "GET",
  url: endpoint,
  success: function(data){
    console.log(data)
    //Labels comming from wevsite.views//
    complete_label = data.complete_label,
    processing_information_label = data.processing_information_label,
    motivation_label = data.motivation_label,
    action_label = data.action_label,
    other_data_label = data.other_data_label,

    //Data comming from wevsite.views//

    team_name_list2 = data.team_name_list2
    info_array = data.info_array
    current_user = data.current_user
    team_list_id = data.team_list_id

    fixed_array = info_array[current_user]

    function random_color(){
      var color = 'rgba(' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256))+ ',' + 0.2 + ')';
    return color
    }


    //ctx//

    var ctx2 = document.getElementById("info_process").getContext('2d');



    //graph 2//
    var info_process = new Chart(ctx2,{
      type: 'radar',
      data: {
            labels: processing_information_label,
            datasets:[{
                    data: fixed_array, //processing_information_data,
                    backgroundColor: random_color()
                      },
                      {

                      backgroundColor: random_color(),
                      data: []
                      }]
            },
      options: {
            legend: {
                position: 'top',
                display: false
            },
            scale: {
                  display: true,
                  ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true,
                          }
                   },
            responsive:true,
            maintainAspectRatio: true,
               }
        });
        //end graph 2//


 $(".pick-chart").change(function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var val = $(this).val();
     if (val != 0) {
         $.ajax({
             method: "GET",
             url: endpoint,
             success: function(data){
                 console.log(data)
                 //Labels coming from website.views//

                 info_array = data.info_array
                 current_user = data.current_user
                 config.data.datasets[0].data = info_array[val];
                 config.data.datasets[1].data = info_array[current_user];
                 mainChart.update();
             }
         });
     } else {
         config.data.datasets[0].data = [];
     }
     mainChart.update();
 });

}
})


</script>
```

Comment: It is not clear to me where this dynamic data that you are talking about is coming from, what code do you use for that?

Comment: @rolfv1 Hi, you are right, I am using AJAX to get the data from views.py file that use the Django REST framework so it look like : var endpoint = 'api/chart/data'


$.ajax({
  method: "GET",
  url: endpoint,
  success: function(data){
    console.log(data)
   info_array = data.info_array
    current_user = data.current_user

where info_array is the data in the form {user_id:[data]} and current user is the id of the current user

Comment: Please edit/update your question and include all relevant source code and give an example of the `AJAX` response.

Comment: @Ben2pop In that case, that `info_array` is already an array that holds the data that you would want to use in your `pick-chart.change` function right? Then the only thing you need is a link between the `val` of the dropdown box and the user_id's in the `info_array`. (And you'd need a global variable for example to store the `info_array` data in)

Comment: I updated the post. Yes Info array contain all the data needed the thing is that in my static example I used 4 static variables, one var fixed_array and the 3 other are like  array["johnny"] that is what I do not know how to do dynamically

Answer (score 0):

If you format your dropdown box as such: (so the user_id in the value of each option)

```
<select name="pick-chart" class="pick-chart">
    <option value="6">Raphael</option>
    ...
</select>
```

You could rewrite your `pick-chart.change` function to something like:

```
$(".pick-chart").change(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var val = $(this).val();
    if (val != 0) {
        $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: endpoint,
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data)
                //Labels coming from website.views//

                info_array = data.info_array
                current_user = data.current_user
                config.data.datasets[0].data = info_array[val];
                config.data.datasets[1].data = info_array[current_user];
                mainChart.update();
            }
        });
    } else {
        config.data.datasets[0].data = [];
    }
    mainChart.update();
});
```

Assuming your data really is dynamic and could change while the user stays at your page. Also assuming that you want to compare `current_user` (which should also be a user_id) in dataset 1, like your fixed data, to a selected other user in dataset 0.

Comment: could you explain me :var val = $(this).val(); and config.data.datasets[0].data please ?

Comment: Those are both already in your own code. First one pulls the value from the select dropdownbox, the second is the data of the first graph in the chart, I presume.

Comment: I am getting an error : Uncaught ReferenceError: config is not defined at this line  config.data.datasets[0].data = info_array[val]; I added my complete code in the edited code V2